# Should I use useEffect in this situation?

Tags: reactjs

I don't know if I am allowed to ask questions like these, but I have a dilemma where I don't know should I use useEffect in the situation I have here:

```
const handleUrlQuery = () => {
    if (params.debouncedValue.length > 0) {
      queryName = "name";
      queryValue = params.debouncedValue;
      return {
        queryName,
        queryValue,
      };
    } else if (params.debouncedValue === "") {
      queryName = "page";
      queryValue = params.page;
      return {
        queryName,
        queryValue,
      };
    }
  };

  handleUrlQuery();

const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}?${queryName}=${queryValue}`;

const { data, error } = useFetch(url);
```

This function is used for changing the query part of the url, now it is supposed to change the queryName and queryValue based on the search value or in this case debounced search value. Now I am confused because I have a feeling that I need to use useEffect, but I am not sure, anyone has any advice on this?

Comment: I personally don't see the need to use useEffect.  You want to update you're `handleUrlQuery` function on every rerender so that it maintains the updated value of `params.debouncedValue` and you're not creating any type of side process.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it is better to ask people that know better than me. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to optimize this code, which unless its in a super heavy component, I don't see too much of a need you could use `useMemo`.

```
const url = useMemo(() => {
    if (params.debouncedValue.length > 0) {
      queryName = "name";
      queryValue = params.debouncedValue;
    } else if (params.debouncedValue === "") {
      queryName = "page";
      queryValue = params.page;
    }
    return `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}?${queryName}=${queryValue}`;
  }, [params.debouncedValue, params.page]);
// don't believe you have to add process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL as a dependency

const { data, error } = useFetch(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't call the function `handleUrlQuery` inside a `useEffect`, it will be called on every re-render, even if `params.debouncedValue` didn't change.

Therefore, you need a `useEffect` if you have other state variables changing, and you only want to call `handleUrlQuery` when *specifically* `params.debouncedValue` changes.

#### [Dummy Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mclaren-rr31h)